# split the time x minutes between two dates mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to create a table where I need to split the time between two dates in X minutes:

Datestart: `DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL X_hours HOUR)`
DateStop: `NOW()`

Split the dates between this data during one hour in 5 minutes means 12 rows with

```
SELECT
(Datestart
Datestart + 5 minutes
Datestart + 10 minutes
....
Datestart + 60 minutes) AS newtimestamps,
SUM(parcels)
WHERE TimeStampRecordParcel >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL X_hours HOUR)
GROUP BY newtimestamps
```

So in the case that there is not `TimeStampRecordParcel` inside the `newtimestamps` the `SUM(parcel)` will be `0`.

I did something similar with

```
SELECT TimeStampRecordParcel AS timeStamp, SUM(parcels) AS Parcels
WHERE TimeStampRecordParcel >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL X_hours HOUR)
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TimeStampRecordParcel) DIV (x_seconds*60);
```

But with It, I just get the rows that have `TimeStampRecordParcel` and not real X time cuts between two dates.

Table:

```
TimeStampRecordParcel   Parcels
2014-10-22 11:03:23      3
2014-10-22 11:08:01      2
2014-10-22 11:11:45      5
2014-10-22 11:34:21      8
2014-10-22 11:45:16      1
2014-10-22 11:48:31      7
2014-10-22 11:51:54      3
2014-10-22 12:01:37      4
```

Table with 5 minutes in one hour with Datestart at '2014-10-22 11:02:35'

```
newtimestamps          SUM(Parcels)
2014-10-22 11:02:35      3
2014-10-22 11:07:35      7
2014-10-22 11:12:35      0
2014-10-22 11:17:35      0
2014-10-22 11:22:35      0
2014-10-22 11:27:35      0
2014-10-22 11:32:35      8
2014-10-22 11:37:35      0
2014-10-22 11:42:35      1
2014-10-22 11:47:35     10
2014-10-22 11:52:35      0
2014-10-22 11:57:35      4
```

somebody can help me with it? I'm starting to get crazy :$

Thank you!!

Comment: Where does a value like `2014-10-22 11:17:35` come from?

Comment: Hi Gordon, This is what I need, to create these values from Datestart: DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL X_hours HOUR)
DateStop: NOW() 

And split this range of time in x seconds

So in the example of this table was DateStart=2014-10-22 11:02:35; DateStop=2014-10-22 12:02:35; splited in 12 rows of 5 minutes increments

Comment: It would make sense to me if the new timestamps started at `11:03:23` or `11:00:00`.  The `11:02:35` doesn't make sense.

Comment: The problem is that i can't look in the timeStamp that the machine recorded to create the trend. Because the machine just record info when there is a new event.
I need to create a new timestamp splited in X minutes and where if the timestamp the machine doesn't recorded nothing during this piece of time force result to 0.
And if there is one or two or n rows in this piece of time i will make the sum of all and get a single row.